# How to use setValue correctly with Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular reactive forms. I wanted to use `setvalue()`to initialize my form with values from my API and then perform a update.I am currently performing a get request to get the product then I am setting my product values to the data that I am getting from my service.I am able to this by passing the `i` to my function which I then pass to my service to get the product by it's id. I am getting all my data from my localhost so I do not have a stackblitz as I don't see how it would help. It would take too long to make dummy data.If there is anything you need to know please let me know in the comments.

Function in my update-product.ts:

```
selectedId(id){
this.id = id +1 ;

this.homeService.getProduct(this.id).subscribe(data => {
 this.product = data;
}); 
this.updateProduct.setValue({
 id: this.product.id,
 productName: this.product.productName,
 category: this.product.category.categoryName,
 fullPrice: this.product.fullPrice,
 salePrice: this.product.salePrice,
 availability: this.product.availability,
 supplier: this.product.supplier.supplierName,
 discount: this.product.discount
});

}
```

I have ternary operator for my form to keep track of which product I want in edit mode. But I notice that there is a delay. I have to click the button twice before the data gets displayed. If I click edit mode on another product the product information from the previous product I selected gets displayed. I believe it's where I have the function located but I am not sure.

When I click on the second product the data from the first product gets displayed, and I have to click it 3 times in total to get the data from current product.

Comment: Generally, it's a good idea to shorten the code up a bit on these. This question is rather intimidating as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **setValue()** needs to be inside of your **subscribe()** otherwise it'll always run before your **subscribe()** finishes.

```
selectedId(id){
    this.id = id + 1;

    this.homeService.getProduct(this.id).subscribe(data => {
        this.product = data;
        this.updateProduct.setValue({
            id: this.product.id,
            productName: this.product.productName,
            category: this.product.category.categoryName,
            fullPrice: this.product.fullPrice,
            salePrice: this.product.salePrice,
            availability: this.product.availability,
            supplier: this.product.supplier.supplierName,
            discount: this.product.discount
        });
    });

    console.log(this.id);
}
```

That would explain why it always takes two tries. If your unsure how this works give this a read: 
https://angular.io/guide/observables

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use ngrx, better way is to create behavioursubject for your editMode

editStarted = new BehaviorSubject(false);
 editItemChanged = new BehaviorSubject({});

create this in your service class and subscribe to it whereever you need.
so once your editStarted or editItemChanged triggers by envoking next() on it component gets notified and can perform what ever code you want to execute.